# currentTab.open(window1) Not opening Window in the tab In Titanium for Android

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I am using Titanium 3.1.2 to build a tabbed android application
The application has two tabs and i open a window in each tab.
I want to be able to open all subsequent windows in the tabs and not as full screen that cover the tab group. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Any misunderstanding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For android ,tabs only appear in first navigations (where you adding tabs in tabgroups).You have to create custom views to show tabs on child windows.

For IOS ,tabs will appear in child windows .If you don't want to show tabs in child windows then set tab window property  `tabBarHidden : true`

```
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    tabBarHidden : true
});
```